# Error, Inserto imagen en buttOn tkinter, NO APARECE LA IMAGEN

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

estoy tratando de colocar una imagen a un Botton de aun aplicación GUI con tkinter, simplemente no aparece.

Aquí importo la librería

```
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

# Botón para copiar nombre

can = Canvas(frame9,bg='red',width=800,height=700)
photo=ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="boton_copiar.png")
can.create_image(150,150,image=photo)

Button(frame9, image=photo, background="pale green", foreground = 'black', 
    font = ('arial', 12, 'bold'), height = 3, width = 20, command = self.copy_name
    ).grid(row =0, column = 0, columnspan = 1, sticky = W + E, pady = 10, padx = 10)
```

Tampoco generar error, simplemente no aparece, quizás es una tontería, o si hay otra manera mas simple de colocar una imagen en un button agradecería la ayuda, saludos y gracias de antemano.

Estoy usando Python 3.8.1 (tags/v3.8.1:1b293b6, Dec 18 2019, 22:39:24) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)] on win32 Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

Comment: Hola Juan ¿ese código está dentro de una función o método de clase?

Comment: Me auto-contesto, no había visto el `self.copy_name`.... Estoy bastante seguro que el problema es el mostrado en la pregunta marcada como duplicada, no se si existirá ser viviente que usando Tkinter no se encontrara tarde o temprano con éste problema... XD. En tu caso bastaría en principio  con hacer algo como: `can._img = photo`. Si no solventa el problema agrega algo más de contexto, el estado de duplicado es reversible si se confirma que no lo es. Saludos.

Comment: Muchas Gracias  FJSevilla, ya aparce la imagen, so que sumamente estrecha, al grado que no se percibe, aunque aumente el valor en esta linea, sigue super estrecha, can.create_image(150,150,image=photo)

Comment: ¿Qué dimensiones tiene la imagen original? Mas que nada para ver si puedo reproducir el problema.

Comment: Listo ya encontré el problema de porque me aparecía muy pequeño, era tema de dimensiones, Muchas Gracias FJSevilla, me sirvió  tu instrucción. Saludos